# Multi Direction parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

Does anyone know where I can get started on trying to program something like this http://www.fillet.com.br/

I have the understanding of parallax but cannot find anything remote to how they did this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that site uses a library called [**Skrollr** which is open-sourced on GitHub](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

They have [another fun example](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/).
And here's [an article with a tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/).

Comment: Note: You can't use this in a jsfiddle out-of-the-box because the effect is based on the scroll position of the document.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will look into the Skrollr .